# How can I read an image path that is stored in a variable?

Tags: python, variables, image-processing, path

I store a path in a variable like this

```py
photo_path = "C:\Users\THIS PC\OneDrive\Documents\ATE\abc.jpg"
```

I want to open it `photo_read = cv2.imread(r"photo_path")`
The `r"photo_path"` doesn't work. Is there any way that I can do that? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the string "photo_path" to the cv2.imread() function instead of the actual path stored in the photo_path variable. Remove quotes from the photo_path and pass the variable directly.

You also need to escape the backslashes, you attempted to use raw literal (r) but code requires minor modification.

```
photo_path = r"C:\Users\THIS PC\OneDrive\Documents\ATE\abc.jpg"
photo_read = cv2.imread(photo_path)
```

Comment: Thank you, if I take the image as input from user by PySimpleGUI, does that mean the image path is added the r by default?

Comment: No, PySimpleGUI does not automatically add an r before the user input image path. The r prefix is used to create a raw string literal, which treats backslashes as literal characters and not escape characters.

Comment: @cam you seem to think that adding “r” in front of an existing string does something. It doesn’t. In Python there is a difference between putting `r” “` and `” “` around your literal strings in code, the literal string is parsed differently. But the *value* created is identical. They’re both plain UNICODE strings.

Comment: Thank you everyone, I've figured it out! Thank you a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `r` while assigning. So that the variable contains a raw string:

```
photo_path = r"C:\Users\THIS PC\OneDrive\Documents\ATE\abc.jpg"
photo_read = cv2.imread(photo_path)
```

Comment: Thank you that will work, but is there anyway I can store the path in a variable first and then add r later to that variable?